# How can I create a wrapper to use blocks for a class that uses callbacks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I'm diving into iOS programming and I'm learning how to use blocks. I have a sucky, over-engineered library that I'm using in my project and it uses a single callback method to handle all data requests...

```
@protocol SuckyClassDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)returnedSuckyData:(NSMutableDictionary*)data;
@end

@interface SuckyClass: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SuckyClassDelegate> delegate;
-(void)getSuckyData;
@end

@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <SuckyClassDelegate>
-(void)requestDataFromSuckyClass;
@end
```

I'd like to create a wrapper class for the SuckyClass that allows me to use blocks when I need to access data from the SuckyClass, but I don't know how to do this.  I'd like to have something like this...

```
@interface SuckyClassWrapper
- (void)requestDataWithSuccessBlock:(void(^)((NSMutableDictionary*)data))successBlock;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
-(void)requestDataFromSuckyClass {
   SuckyClassWrapper *wrapper = [[SuckyClassWrapper alloc] init];
   [wrapper requestDataWithSuccessBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *data) {
       NSLog(@"%@", data);
   }
}
@end
```

...but I can't figure out how to convert the callback process into blocks. Can anyhow give me some direction here?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

By the way, I just whipped up the code without testing it, so I apologize if there are any typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to copy the completion block to a class iVar that you can then call later.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^errorHandler)(NSError *);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^successHandler)(NSString *);
```

Here is a method that saves two blocks for use later and then calls another class method:

```
- (void)methodWithErrorHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock successHandler: (void(^)(NSString *data))successBlock
{
    // Copy the blocks to use later
    self.successHandler = successBlock;
    self.errorHandler = errorBlock;

    // Run code
    [self doOtherThings];
}
```

Later - when what we want to do has completed, we have another method that we call to run the blocks. In this silly example code we check to see if a class property `self.error` is `nil`. If it is not `nil`, we send that error to our saved error block. If it is `nil`, we pass `self.data` to the success block.

```
- (void)finishThingsUp
{
    // Check to see if we should call the error block or the success block
    if (self.error) {
        self.errorHandler(self.error);
    } else {
        self.successHandler(self.data);
    }
    // Clean up the blocks
    self.errorHandler = nil;
    self.successHandler = nil;
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, since Objective-C doesn't support class variables, you're using declared properties `self.successHandler` and `self.errorHandler` to assign copies of the blocks to class _instance_ variables.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @NSBum

Comment: sure.  +1 for compact solution.

Comment: Also, you should be declaring your block properties as copy, so the explicit -copy's are not needed.

Comment: You should also nil out both block properties at the end of `finishThingsUp` to avoid leaking the objects referenced in the blocks.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherPickslay and @CodaFi! I've made those changes to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

We could use like this:

```
typedef void (^SuccessDataBlock)(NSMutableDictionary *);
@interface SuckyClassWrapper : NSObject <SuckyClassDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *inputData;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) SuccessDataBlock completionHandler;

    + (id)requestData:(NSData *)data successBlock:(SuccessDataBlock)handler;
@end

@implementation SuckyClassWrapper

@synthesize inputData;
@synthesize completionHandler;

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data completionHandler:(SuccessDataBlock)handler

{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        inputData = [data retain];
        self.completionHandler = handler;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)requestData:(NSData *)data successBlock:(SuccessDataBlock)handler
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithData:data completionHandler:handler] autorelease];
}

//implement SuckyClass delegate
- (void)returnedSuckyData:(NSMutableDictionary *)data
{
    self.completionHandler(data);
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
SuckyClassWrapper *wrapper = [SuckyClassWrapper requestData:data successBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *successData) {
    //your code here
}];
```